# Scala case class: reset field to default value on .copy() call

Tags: scala, case-class

I want to track if `case class` was "checked" since the last update. This means flipping the boolean flag to `true` after each "check" and flipping back to `false` after `case class` was updated (via `.copy` call). However, I don't know how to do the latter part.

So, how to reset boolean flag inside `case class` to `false` after each update (e.g. `.copy` call)?

I have two solutions:

1. Change flag manually in each place of our codebase: add `checked = false` in each `.copy` call. (this solution seems bad, as someone can create .copy without resetting my flag. Also, there are hundreds of `.copy()` calls in a codebase)

```
case class A(..., checked: Boolean)

// somewhere in the code
a.copy(..., checked = false)
```

2. Add var with default parameter set to false. This way on each `.copy()` call it will be reseted:

```
case class A(...) {
 var checked: Boolean = false
}
```

Second one seems better, but I don't really like this mutability in `case class`.

Are there any other ways (overriding `.copy()`?) to achive similar results w/o introducing `var`?

Comment: Do you realize that `copy` is creating a new class? so even if you modify the variable in the old instance you usually will be using the new one instance. It is not clear what exactly do you want and why.

Comment: I do realize it. This is exactly why a trick with `var` will work.

Comment: So you want to have a check that someone called `copy` on your case class? why? This sound like an XY-problem.

Comment: Not possible with automatically generated methods. You can implement your own `.copy` which would have some logic, although this looks like you want to have a normal class, not an immutable case class.

Comment: Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, I see your point about XY-problem. I have a pipeline of `Actors` that may update the case class during it passing through each of them. My goal is to know that the `case class` was changed since the last time I "checked" (check ~= validation with a roundtrip to DB, so I don't want to validate it in case nothing changed). The proper way of doing it may include creating my own `copy`/manually flipping the `checked` field to false after each `.copy`. It just codebase so huge and hard to refactor, that I've tried to find an easier way of doing so.

Comment: @YevheniiPopadiuk effectively it seems you do not want an immutable case class but rather a mutable class, since again it seems you do not want to create a copy of the class, you want to modify its contents. - In any case, I may suggest having that checked flag outside of the class _(or at least not visible outside of the actor)_.

Comment: Honestly, the more Akka way to handle this (assuming that the `case class` is isomorphic to at least one record in your DB) is to designate an actor which owns this `case class` and have the actors it's currently passing through interact with that actor (i.e. everything that they want to change is now done by a message to the designated actor).  Then only the designated actor interacts with the DB and it knows whether there's been a change.